# How to create a hovered toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[image]

How to create a hovered toolbar?
Clicking to expand the ToolBar will not shrink the Canvas.

**Expander** works for expanding, but the canvas will get shrinked.

```
<UserControl x:Class="smartgrid.studio.View.GraphicEditorView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:smartgrid.studio.Model"
         xmlns:studio="clr-namespace:smartgrid.studio"
         xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1000">
<DockPanel>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="left" Header ="Toolbar" FontSize="18" ExpandDirection="Up">
        <TreeView Name="GraphicEditorEntityTree" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding GraphicEditorEntities}"/>
    </Expander>
    <Canvas/>
</DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: There, I removed the comments for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overlay things by putting them in a `Grid` without rows or columns, the sizing of your toolbar is an independent matter (you can still use an expander for that).

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx

**Panel.ZIndex** might be the solution.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
 <Grid x:Name="Toolbar" Panel.ZIndex="1000" Visibility="Collapsed">
  </Grid>
  <canvas />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Note that the ZIndex is only relevant if you do not add the controls in the order you want them Z-index-wise, e.g. if you add a `Button` as the very first control but want it on top and not at the bottom as it would be normally.